# Validate before Posting a text or an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a self-learning Rails application (the source code can be found [here](http://github.com/stefioan/9FUN). I want to validate the presence of the content before posting a text or an image:

[image: here].

Those are my [models](https://gist.github.com/stefioan/7723901) or look below:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope { order ("created_at DESC")}
  belongs_to :content, polymorphic: true
  has_reputation :votes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
end

class PhotoPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, styles: {
    post: "200x200>"
  }
end

class TextPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body
end
```

Here are my [controllers](https://gist.github.com/stefioan/7723846) in case they have a relation with this. Any other files can be found in my Github account. I am sure it will be messy to copy the whole project (that is why I am giving links for the controllers and for my project).

So what I have tried so far. (I tried those on the Posts Model)

=> Using validates_associated

```
validates_associated :content, :text_post
```

and getting an error "undefined method `text_post' for #Post:0x517c848>"

=> Used validates

```
   validates :content, :presence => true
```

and getting no error however a post is created with no text.

```
validates :body, :presence => true
```

and getting an error "undefined method `body' for #Post:0x513e4a8>"

If you need any other information please let me know and I will provide it asap.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm kind of confused what you are trying to achieve here. Why do you have Post, TextPost and PhotoPost models? You have no relation structure in PhotoPost and TextPost and the Post model has a polymorphic relation pointing nowhere o.O

Comment: "belongs_to :content, polymorphic: true", then I use content_type and content_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem you have quite a confusing model setup with some key missing relation rules. E.g. Polymorphic rule which is not being utilised and a has_many relation between User and Post with no sign a of a user_id value in the Post model. Here is how I would set it up:

**User.rb**

```
def User << ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :text_posts
   has_many :photo_posts
end
```

**TextPost.rb**

```
def TextPost << ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :body, :user_id
   belongs_to :user
   validates :body, :presence => true
end
```

**PhotoPost.rb**

```
def PhotoPost << ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :image, :user_id
   belongs_to :user
   validates :file, :presence => true, :format => {
      :with => %r{\.(gif|png|jpg)$}i,
      :message => "must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image."
   }
end
```

Then in your view you would need to do:

```
<%= form_for @text_post do |f| %>
# ...
<% end %>
```

And in your controller you can modify the create method to include the current_user from devise and assign it to the new text post record (user_id attribute):

**text_posts_controller.rb**

```
def create 
   @text_post = current_user.text_posts.new(params[:text_post])
end
```

This adheres more to the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle which Ruby on Rails excels at - you shouldn't be writing alot of code to just create a new record.

I would advise on reading up on some Ruby on Rails standard and best practises. You shouldn't need to create a method in the Dashboard Model in order to create a new TextPost or PhotoPost record. This is a very confusing way of going about it; instead you should be utilising the power of ActiveRecord relation.

I would advise checking out [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/). They have alot of fulfilling content.

Comment: This "structure" was created by Matthew Mongeau, developer at Thoughtbot.

Comment: Ok. I can't seem to understand why you need to create a new record in a foreign model's method, i.e: `@dashboard.new_text_post ... def new_text_post TextPost.new end`. Could you explain the reasoning behind this approach?

Comment: I followed a workshop doing all this. I can't really explain the reasoning behind this approach however thoughbot keeps a forum and can provide such explanation.